# Saving Excel as PDF fitting everything into one page not working

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

As part of the project, I need to save some range of Excel cells as a PDF file, still making everything fit in one page. If there are more data than fit to one page, it needs to be nicely trimmed and go to the 2nd page.

My code saves an Excel file as PDF, but there are 8 pages now, and the data are displayed big and there is a lot of blank spaces around each edge of the page.
Also, not all columns are fit in one page. It is like the first page has column A through column G, and later in other pages, I see column H through column M, but this is not what I want.

```
var excelPath = "My Excel file path.xlsx";    //Excel file path
var pdfPath = "My PDf file path.pdf";  //Pdf file path
var sheetName = "25. Data";  //Excel sheet name to get data from 
var printRange = "A1:M70";  //Area that needs to be included in PDF

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(excelPath);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[sheetName];
ws.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = printRange;
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;
wb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, pdfPath);
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code??

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I didn't know why but `PageSetup.Zoom` was set to 100 by default. Adding

```
ws.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
```

fixed the issue. Microsoft page says if this value is set to `true`, `FitToPagesTall` and `FitToPagesWide` will be **ignored**.